# Changing character encoding from Unicode to Ascii

Tags: textedit, file-conversion, encoding, unicode

I need to convert the *character encoding* in some text files created by a third-party app on my MBP Catalina 10.15.6.  I'm in unfamiliar waters here, so please indulge my ignorance.  Also, please note that the 3rd party app is **not** the subject of this question - understanding how to reconcile the different character sets used in macOS is the subject.

I use an application ([LTspice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTspice#LTspice_XVII)) on my MBP occasionally.  There is also a Windows version of LTspice.  LTspice provides a GUI for creating a circuit schematic, and LTspice creates a plain text file (.asc extension) to encode the schematic and other directives and parameters created in the LTspice GUI; this is the file I need to convert.

I assumed the .asc files were not ASCII-encoded, and so I ran the `file` utility on the `.asc` file to learn how they were encoded:

```
% file -I '/Users/seamus/Documents/LTspice/Rounding demo-MacMod.asc'
/Users/seamus/Documents/LTspice/Rounding demo-MacMod.asc: application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

***binary?!***...  This made no sense to me. I can open and edit this file in `TextEdit`.  All of the characters are recognizable ASCII characters - which I understand to be a [subset of UTF-8](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/97247/what-is-the-advantage-of-choosing-ascii-encoding-over-utf-8).

My next step was to open the file in the `BBedit` app.  This revealed new information.  According to `BBedit`, the `demo-MacMod.asc` file reported by `file -I` as binary is actually: **"UTF-16 Little Endian"** format.  I know this is confusing... In an effort to clarify, I've placed a couple of screenshots below to illustrate how this file is rendered in `BBedit` and `TextEdit`.  The extra byte (**¿**) in the `BBedit` screenshot is a NUL.

I need a method (that I can *automate/script*) to convert these **"UTF-16 Little Endian"** files to **"US-ASCII"**. I thought that the `iconv` tool would be perfect for this job:

```
iconv -l
...
# long list of character encodings which included:
US-ASCII
UCS-2LE UNICODELITTLE
```

`UCS-2LE UNICODELITTLE` looked like the best match to **"UTF-16 Little Endian"**, but:

```
% iconv -f 'UCS-2LE UNICODELITTLE' -t 'US-ASCII' '/Users/seamus/Documents/LTspice/Rounding demo-MacMod.asc' > '/Users/seamus/Documents/LTspice/Rounding demo-MacMod-iconvASCII.asc'
iconv: conversion from UCS-2LE UNICODELITTLE unsupported
iconv: try 'iconv -l' to get the list of supported encodings
```

I don't know why I get this response. Clearly `iconv -l` says that `UCS-2LE UNICODELITTLE` ***is supported.*** Whether it's the **correct** match for **"UTF-16 Little Endian"** is another question, but I find nothing in the list that looks to be a better match.

So this is the gist of my question. I think it could be answered in one of two ways:

1. What is my error in the use of `iconv`, or in my reading of `man iconv` or `iconv -l`?
2. Is there another option for converting **"UTF-16 Little Endian"** to **"US-ASCII"** that can be automated/scripted?

### SCREENSHOTS:

#### in TextEdit:

[image]

#### in BBedit:

[image]

Comment: It's more correct to describe UTF-8 as a superset on ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

With [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/) this is easy. First open the file in BBEdit. If you let BBEdit install its command line tool you can even do this from Terminal with `bbedit /path/to/filename`. If the file has opened as the wrong encoding, select `File > Reopen Using Encoding > correct encoding`. I think it would be worth trying reopening using `UTF-16 Little-Endian` & `UTF-16 Little-Endian, no BOM` to see if either of those has the file open as desired. When you have the file correctly opened, select `File > Save As...`. In the Save As dialog box you can choose the desired encoding, & also the line ending type if that matters.

For dealing with inverted red question marks, probably null (ASCII 0), select `Text > Zap Gremlins...` for the dialog below...

[image]

Using the options shown there should give a state like what you see in TextEdit. Try different options on copies of a couple of your files.

Because BBEdit has a command line tool, you should be able script it once you have the correct options. BBEdit also works with AppleScript & Automator.

You can download BBEdit for free from the link I've given. It will start in demo mode, & when the demo mode expires it will continue to run in free mode where the features you need are still available.

Comment: Thanks - I thought I made it clear in my Q that this can be done in BBedit, but the answer I need is one that I can script/automate: `Is there another option for converting "UTF-16 Little Endian" to "US-ASCII" that can be automated/scripted?`

Comment: Oops! I left out an entire portion of my intended answer. Look again in a few minutes.

Comment: I've got a BBedit license (used it for years & love it), so I'll look into the command-line tool. I have asked BBedit tech support about automation options though, and they didn't mention the cmd-line tool...

Comment: And don't overlook `man bbedit` to find out what the command line tool does for you.

Comment: Right, but `man bbedit` doesn't **seem** to suggest there is any support for changing encoding used in a file. The GUI certainly has it -  "Zap Gremlins" & search & replace at least. I just don't see any way to invoke those using the cmdline ver of `bbedit`

Comment: I've just added a bit about choices in `Reopen Using Encoding...`.

Comment: Unix Command Line stuff begins on page 345 of the manual. There's a lot that I wasn't aware of until I looked just now.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. What is my error in the use of iconv, or in my reading of man iconv or iconv -l?

The error was simply *mis-reading* the output of `iconv -l`:

```
iconv -l
...
# long list of character encodings which included:
US-ASCII
UCS-2LE UNICODELITTLE
```

The character encoding is correctly read as `UCS-2LE` - **not** `UCS-2LE UNICODELITTLE`. Using that as the option in `iconv`:

```
% iconv -f 'UCS-2LE' -t 'US-ASCII' '/Users/seamus/Documents/LTspice/Rounding demo-MacMod.asc' > '/Users/seamus/Documents/LTspice/Rounding demo-MacMod-iconvASCII.asc'
```

Which gives the desired conversion from **"UTF-16 Little Endian"** to **"US-ASCII"**

As far as the question re `file -I` reporting this text file as a **binary** file - I have no clue at this time.

Comment: Binary as it has windows line endings and bytes not in 1-127 ie non ascII. So can't be read and the contents interpreted or at least does not meet a known byte sequence

Comment: @mmmmmm: Are you saying, "If it's not ASCII, then it's binary"? The TextEdt app opens and renders it perfecty - just as if it were an ASCII file.

Comment: Texted it probably uses a different algorithm to work out what the file is. Note it is in utf16 of some sort not ascii